# Random graphs: A random graph induces a distribution on each link. Do they uniquely determine the graph?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-graphs

Let $G$ be a random graph with $n$ nodes, with the nodes numbered. $G$ induces a distribution in the set of all graphs of $n$ nodes and we can identify this distribution with $G$.

Given the nodes $i,j$, we consider the Bernoulli random variable $a_{ij}$ which is $1$ when the link $i,j$ exists in $G$. Do the distributions of $a_{ij}, \forall i,j$ uniquely determine the distribution of $G$?

Comment: It depends on the assumption you make on G. In general,  there could be correlation between edges, and that case can't be captured by separate $a_{ij}$ distributions.

Comment: Is it safe to say that this is true when all $a_{ij}$ are independent?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: It is true in general as well. The correspondence here is between a graph and its adjacency matrix, whose entries take values only 0 and 1.